# Transposing Data Out within SQL Table not using Pivot option

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, pivot, sql-server-2017

I'm trying to Transpose Data in a SQL Table, but this is a bit of custom transposing technique and possible concatenation of values into one table cell.

Below is a sample data set. From `[master].[dbo].[OLE DB Destination 3]`

```
_ParentKey Field |name                          |type
1                |CHEVRON MIDCONTINENT LP       |Grantor
1                |CHEVRON USA INC               |Grantor
1                |UNION OIL CO                  |Grantor
1                |XBM PRODUCTION LP             |Grantor
1                |CASILLAS PETROLEUM            |Grantee
2                |OSAGE OIL AND GAS PROPERTIES  |Grantor
2                |CASILLAS PETROLEUM            |Grantee
```

Below is the desired out put of the query

```
_ParentKey Field |Grantor                                                               |Grantee
1                |CHEVRON MIDCONTINENT LP, CHEVRON USA INC, UNION OIL, XBM PRODUCTION LP|CASILLAS PETROLEUM
2                |OSAGE OIL AND GAS PROPERTIES                                          |CASILLAS PETROLEUM
```

I'm assuming the `_ParentKey Field` field would be the "primary key" to transpose this data out. Every Name in the "name" column will either have a Grantor or Grantee Type.
Disclaimer: I only know basic SQL up to Joining, sub-queries and some data manipulation.

Comment: Check out STRING_AGG https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend conditional aggregation and string aggregation function `string_agg()`:

```
select 
    _ParentKey,
    string_agg(case when type = 'Grantor' then name end, ', ') grantor,
    string_agg(case when type = 'Grantee' then name end, ', ') grantee
from mytable
group by _ParentKey
```

Comment: Would anyone know how to convert this into SQL Query into VBA code?